# WPF ListView MouseOver Item

Tags: wpf, listview, mouseover

For the wpf listview , in the **Mouse Over** event how do i get a reference to the item that the mouse cursor is on ?

Regards,
MadSeb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the MouseOver event from the listViewItem that the mouse is over, not the one from the listview itself.

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    ListView listView = new ListView();
    ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem();

    listViewItem.MouseMove += myMouseMoveEvent;

    listView.Items.Add(listViewItem);

}

private void myMouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem) sender;
    // now you can handle the events with this item....
}
```