# WPF XAML ListView MouseOverItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, mouseover

Do you know is it possible to get element on MouseOver from ListView in WPF using XAML?
I would like to bind mouse over element to command parameter.

What should I type in Path ?

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetOnMousePlayerCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=leftPlayersListViewGame, Path=XXX}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Probably I have to do it in another way ? Could you tell my how ?

Comment: Do you like to know what kind of UI element is present in the ListView, when Mouseover happpens to it?

Comment: This qestion's answer should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294945/wpf-listview-mouseover-item

Comment: ListView associate my custom control;
Gus, thank You but, does it possible do it without code behind ?

Comment: you want to access the sender of the MouseEnter Event from the command in the associated ViewModel, Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking to access the Event Args here how you should proceed:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=MouseEnterCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
 </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

```
private RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs> _mouseEnterCommand;
public RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs> MouseEnterCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _mouseEnterCommand
            ?? (_mouseEnterCommand= new RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs>(
            (s) =>
            {
                //your logic 
            }));
    }
}
```

but if you are looking for the sender of the Event, so here is your answer Pal :
[Passing event args and sender to the RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963830/passing-event-args-and-sender-to-the-relaycommand)